# Difference between user-seed.conf file and passwd file in splunk universal forwarder installation

Tags: splunk

I am working on creation of automation script to install splunk universal forwarder. I wanted to understand more on user-seed.conf file and passwd file being created.

As we know, installing splunk UF asks for creation of administrator account when we start the splunk service and accept license.

Step 1:

```
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes
```

When we try to add forwarder to indexer connection , it asks us to authenticate with same username and password.

Step 2 :

```
 /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk add forward-server test_server:9997
```

As per my understanding this authentication revolves around user-seed.conf file and passwd.conf file

```
user-seed.conf - $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local
passwd - $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/passwd
```

Scenarios I faced :

1. sometimes the authentication in step 2 was failing, in that case I saw only user-seed.conf file was created though I change admin username and password
2. Authentication was successful in step 2 and here only passwd file was being created , though I changed username and password of admin.
3. sometimes add forwarder was working with admin account authentication.

Now, my script is working and I am in point 2 . But I am stuck in understanding why the above scenarios happened ? The above scenarios are my observations, still I am unclear and confused.

Please can anyone help me in understanding this better ?
what is the actual difference between user-seed and passwd conf file ?
Why did I see only user-seed conf file being created and not passwd ?

Apologies , if my observations is completely wrong. I am newbiew to this. I went through many blogs over Internet, still not soo clear. Please help me with your inputs .

Thanks in advance,
NVP

Answer (score 0):

The `user-seed.conf` file is used only to load credentials when Splunk starts.  Once the credentials are stored in etc/passwd user-seed.conf is deleted.  Thereafter, only passwd is used to authenticate users.

You don't need credentials to configure a forwarder, though.  All you need to do is edit the appropriate .conf file and then restart the forwarder.

Comment: It does asks for username and password sometimes.


On you saying this,  I launched ec2 instance and tried UF installation and configuration. Now, I dont see username and password being asked .

It asked me to create splunk admin account when start/booting the splunk service and accepting license.

In the next step, adding server to indexer configuration (creating outputs.conf) file, now it didnot ask for authentication.

Do you have any idea why it does asks sometimes and why it doesn't ?

Comment: Splunk will ask for credentials for many CLI commands.  I don't have a list of which commands need creds and which do not.  Editing configuration files is done outside of Splunk so it cannot ask for credentials for that.